# Datastore backup import: Failed to read bucket "XYZ" is not accessible

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, database-backups

I'm working with two separate projects. One is for production, the other dev.

I have backed up the production datastore into a bucket. Now I want to import that into the dev datastore. But when I try, I get the message:

Failed to read bucket: Bucket "the.bucket.name" is not accessible

I thought it might be permissions, I added the dev project with owners-devid and editors-devid and my-email as owners of the bucket. But still got the same error.

gsutil ls working for me, I think that I am not having an issue specifying the bucket.

Comment: You might want to take a look at the documentation on this feature. This might be related: "[...]The permissions set in the previous step are not retroactive to existing backups, so the target app will not be able to access those earlier backups".

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/console/datastoreadmin#restoring_data_to_another_app

Answer (score 2):

The issue I had was that I was adding the dev project into permissions as

```
    Project   editors-##############                       Editor
```

vs

```
    User      [project name]@appspot.gserviceaccount.com   Editor
```

The datastore import happens under the user account.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. Setting the permissions as:

```
 User      [project name]@appspot.gserviceaccount.com   Writer
```

allows to perform the backup in another project bucket, however it doesn't allow to import from that bucket. I also tried to set owner permission, but the result was the same.
The error reported is:

```
Requested path https://storage.googleapis.com/[bucket_name]/[id_backup_info].info is not accessible/access denied
```

Comment: Finally I solved the problem. You have to set permissions in the bucket, buty you also have to set the same permissions in the file (inside the bucket) which has the information of the backup you want to import. If you go into the bucket, you'll see files related to your entities and also other files which have the information about the backups. You have to find the file about the backup you want to import and set permissions.